Setting appsettings after clickonce install
I have an .net 4.5.1 application that is installed via ClickOnce deploy.
For that I publish the app as a cd-rom, and install it via setup.exe.
Depending where I install it I need to set up an appsetting with a path to a directory but I only know that after installation and this directory can be changed after some time.
How can I set this app setting without to reinstall everything? Or is better use another approach like an environment variable?
Regards
